# How to hide com.xamarin.ios version from info.plist?

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have developed an iOS app using Xamarin forms. After taking release build when I extract info.plist, few additional properties has been added in the plist file. Example com.xamarin.ios version. See the attached image.

I dont want to show this version information in plsit.

Can anyone help me?

[image: Screenshot of plist]

Comment: It is necessary .If you delete the item ,It will cause some issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually we got this issue from Penetration testing team. They said, if we show this in public it will lead to hacking. Do you have any option to hide from the list instead of removing?